# Grails yui-minify-resources and lesscss-resources conflict

Tags: grails, resources, yui

I have my grails application that use *lesscss-resources* plugin (v 1.3.0.3). I would like to use also the *yui-minify-resources* plugin (v. 0.1.5).
I installed the plugin using:

```
grails install-plugin yui-minify-resources
```

But now when I try to start the application I have an exception:

```
2012-10-15 12:58:48,901 ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager  - Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [resources:1.1.6]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/mozilla/javascript/Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/mozilla/javascript/Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/mozilla/javascript/Parser.parse(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode;
at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.parse(JavaScriptCompressor.java:312)
at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.JavaScriptCompressor.<init>(JavaScriptCompressor.java:533)
at com.blockconsult.yuiminifyresources.YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper$_map_closure1.doCall(YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper.groovy:29)
at com.blockconsult.yuiminifyresources.YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper.map(YuiJsMinifyResourceMapper.groovy:28)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMapper.invoke(ResourceMapper.groovy:139)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.mapper.ResourceMapper.invokeIfNotExcluded(ResourceMapper.groovy:128)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.applyMappers(ResourceProcessor.groovy:587)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:533)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_prepareSingleDeclaredResource_closure12.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:602)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.util.ResourceMetaStore.addDeclaredResource(ResourceMetaStore.groovy:29)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareSingleDeclaredResource(ResourceProcessor.groovy:600)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor$_prepareResourceBatch_closure14.doCall(ResourceProcessor.groovy:625)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessorBatch.each(ResourceProcessorBatch.groovy:8)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.prepareResourceBatch(ResourceProcessor.groovy:621)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.resourcesChanged(ResourceProcessor.groovy:804)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.loadModules(ResourceProcessor.groovy:800)
at org.grails.plugin.resource.ResourceProcessor.reloadAll(ResourceProcessor.groovy:1056)
at ResourcesGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(ResourcesGrailsPlugin.groovy:172)
... 5 more
```

I think I have this error due the fact that (how the documentation says) YUI minify use an alternative version of Rhino, that is a dependency of lesscss resources plugin.
I tried to exlcude the dependency, but just tried 'cause it seems don't work.
Here is my *Config.groov*:

```
plugins{
    compile (":lesscss-resources:1.3.0.3"){
        excludes 'rhino:1.7R3'
    }
}
```

Does someone has managed the same situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem putting the rhino dependency directly in the lib folder. You can download it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Download_Rhino

Comment: Did you copy the whole download directory to /lib or did you have to build the dependency first?

Comment: I just copied the js.jar after extracting the file downloaded from https://github.com/downloads/mozilla/rhino/rhino1_7R4.zip